# How can I overwrite an array using Ractive?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ractivejs

I have a componet that updates an array on it's parent. Specifically, it takes additions, and **creates an entirely new array that has been sorted, overwriting the original array**.

```
var sortedUpdatedDomainNames = updatedProposedDomainNames.sort(sorts.domainName)
// even though we sort them, after setting the value, getting it returns the unsorted items
debugger;
```

Typing in the debugger here:

```
sortedUpdatedDomainNames
(4) ["example.com", "www.example.com", "swag.com", "www.swag.com"]
```

OK that works. The array items are sorted (using `sorts.domainName` which puts www immediately after parent domains)

```
await parentComponent.set('order.proposedDomainNames', sortedUpdatedDomainNames)
```

Here's **the first issue**: the DOM doesn't update poroperly, some items are duplicated in the DOM even though they're not duplicated in the data.

Running `parentComponent.update` fixes these duplications, however:

```
// Work around odd ractive bug where DOM doesn't update properly
// Trigger an update manually using .update()
// TODO: find proper fix!
await parentComponent.update('order.proposedDomainNames');
```

Her's the **second issue**: the values are now unsorted (well, they're sorted alphabetically now, which isn't what I want).

```
parentComponent.get('order.proposedDomainNames');
(4) ["example.com", "swag.com", "www.example.com", "www.swag.com"]
```

**How can I overwrite an array using Ractive?**

Please do not submit answers re: [`ractive.splice()`](https://ractive.js.org/v0.x/0.8/ractive-splice) etc - I do not know in advance the index where the data will be inserted, I simply wish to sort the entire array and update it.

Comment: Is the array mapped from the parent, or are you passing it in in some other way?

Comment: Also check out `set('path.to.array', ref, { shuffle: true })`, which is similar to splicing but across the whole array. You can use it to sort the array outside of Ractive's purview and update it non-destructively.

Comment: @ChrisReeves I;m not sure what 'mapped from' means. The array is on the parent, but set by the child component. Otherwise could you please reword the question? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, was on vacation. By mapped, I mean as in `<component array="{{array.in.parent}}" />`. If it's mapped like that, when you `this.set('array', [...])` from the component, it should behave in exactly the same way as `this.set('array.in.parent', [...])` in the parent.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisReeves. Alas using `ractive.set()` with `shuffle` enabled still creates the DOM mismatch: prntscr.com/gv6zea . Running `orderStatusUI.update('order.proposedDomainNames')` immediately afterwards though fixes the DOM to accurately reflect the list.

Comment: @ChrisReeves thanks for your suggestiosn to `set()` options. Even thoug hthe array is just of strings, using `deep` triggers a correct DOM update. Reverting it back to `shuffle` fails. I'm not quite sure why though and would appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Using [the `deep` option for `ractive.set()`](https://ractive.js.org/api/#ractiveset) ensures the DOM updates to match the new array values - even though the array is a simple array of primitives.

```
await parentComponent.set('order.proposedDomainNames', sortedUpdatedDomainNames, { deep: true })
```

I also tried `shuffle`, which was suggested, but this does not work and the DOM is still inconsistent with the array value when using `shuffle`.

Though the issue is solved, I'm still interested in **why** `deep` was needed to make the DOM update correctly, so if you have your own answer to that, add it and I'l; accept it!